# Dynamically fire different activerecord queries using procs in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have many different classes that inherit from `Tree` and each of them implements a method called `grow!` but with a slightly different ActiveRecord implementation. Say each method begins with an ActiveRecord query to find the right trees to grow with something like:

```
trees = Tree
          .joins(:fruits)
          .where(land_id: land.id)
          .where(fruits: { sweet: true })
          .where(fruits: { season_id: season.id })
```

Say the part we want to swap out from query to query is this part:

`.where(fruits: { sweet: true })`

Say we want to then build a `WinterTree` class and its own grow method but it only grows non sweet fruits and so we want to return trees that only grow non-sweet fruits. Is there anyway to not have to rewrite the rest of the query and only swap out that one piece of the query and maybe write the rest of  the query in the parent `Tree` class? Is there anyway to call AR segments of queries dynamically?

Comment: I found it easy to build dynamic queries using where statements in sql such as:  Tree.joins(:fruits).where("land_id = ?", land.id ) etc

Comment: Mind fleshing this out as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found it easy to build dynamic queries using where statements in sql such as: `Tree.joins(:fruits).where("land_id = ?", land.id )` etc. Below is what I did yesterday to give you some idea of what I'm talking about but you'll need  to extrapolate it to fit your needs:

```
query = ''
counter = 1
sets_of_data_ill_query.each do |set|
  if counter == 1
    query += "district = '#{set[0]}' AND second_district = '#{set[1]}'"
  else
    query += " OR district = '#{set[0].to_s}' AND second_district = '#{set[1]}'"
  end
end
voters = Voter.where(query)
```

NOTE: I knew the data I was querying was safe so I just used the raw info but you'll want to do it as I showed in the first paragraph with `?`escaping values if it's data that will be entered by users.  Also, since you're chaining where statements you would want to use an "AND" instead of where I used "OR" if you need to loop through sets etc.